# Confusion in destructuring in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

In the following JS (es6) code, what is going on with the variables inside of the curly braces with the colon?

```
const { foo: bar } = ...
```

Normally when you see this it is doing variable assignment from right to left, as in Objects. In objects it would assign the variable `bar` to the object key `foo`, but that doesn't seem to be what is going on here. What is this doing?

Comment: Yes, it is destructuring.

Comment: @loganfsmyth, can you tell me what is happening there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is best to think of destructuring kind of like the opposite of declaring an object, so where

```
const hidingSpotConnection = ...
const obj = { connectionType: hidingSpotConnection };
```

would make an object `obj` with a key `connectionType` containing the value from the `hidingSpotConnection` variable,

```
const { connectionType: hidingSpotConnection } = ...
```

takes the value from the `connectionType` key and stores it in a variable called `hidingSpotConnection`.

Comment: Such an elegant explanation that immediately demystified the subject. Thanks.